# Solve a matrix valued differential equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-analysis

I am trying to solve a particular system of ODE's `dF/dt = A*F, F_initial = eye(9)`. Being a Matlab novice, I am trying to somehow use the implemented `ode45` function, and I found useful advises online. However, all of them assume A to be constant, while in my case the matrix `A` is a function of `t`, in other words, `A` changes with each time step.

I have solved `A` separately and stored it in a 9x9xN array (because my grid is `t = 0:dt:2`, `N=2/dt` is the number of time-steps, and `A(:,:,i)` corresponds to it's value at the i-th time step). But I can't implement this array in `ode45` to eventually solve my ODE.

Any help is welcomed, and please tell me if I have missed anything important while explaining my problem. Thank you

Comment: Is `A` itself the solution of a differential equation? What do you mean with "I have solved `A` separately"? Do you know the `reshape` command?

Comment: A at a specific time t_n, is the Jacobian ( i.e partial derivative matrix) of the 3x3 matrix valued function Q(t_n, **x**) where **x** is a 3x3 matrix. Since both the input and output of Q at time t_n have 9 dimensions, it's Jacobian is 9x9, and changes with respect to t. I haven't heard of `reshape`, but I think that it may be what I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, F must be a column vector when using ode45. You won't ever get a result by setting F_initial = eye(9), you'd need F = ones(9,1).

Also, ode45 [(documentation here, check tspan section)](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) doesn't necessarily evaluate your function at the timesteps that you give it, so you can't pre-compute the A matrix. Here I'm going to assume that F is a column vector and A is a matrix which acts on it, which can be computed each timestep. If this is the case, then we can just include A in the function passed to ode45, like so:

```
F_initial = ones(9,1);
dt = 0.01;
tspan = 0:2/dt:2;
[t, F] = ode45(@(t,F) foo(t, F, Ainput), tspan, F_initial);

function f = foo(t, F, Ainput)
    A = calculate_A(t, Ainput);
    f = A*F;
end

function A = calculate_A(t, Ainput)
    %some logic, calculate A based on inputs and timestep
    A = ones(9,9)*sqrt(t)*Ainput;
end
```

The @(x) f(x,y) basically creates a new [anonymous function](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) which allows you to treat y as a constant in the calculation.

Hope this is helpful, let me know if I've misunderstood something or if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you it is indeed helpful. My initial condition is in fact `eye(9)`, and `F` is a 9x9 matrix. Should I somehow turn `F` into column form, or just use `ode45` 9 times for each column vector?

Comment: Definitely just turn F into column form using `reshape` as LutzL suggested. You can make it really easy for yourself by just using `reshape` at the start of the ODE function to turn the F column vector into a matrix, then turning it back into a column vector at the end.